# I have written mergesort 2 different ways, is the space complexity better in one of them over the other?

Tags: python, mergesort, space-complexity

I have been practicing algorithms and data structures lately and got to this part https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html on mergesort of an online book. The book gives an implementation for the algorithm and I tried rewriting it so it used less space, here is my code (please refer to the link for the book's code):

```
def mergeSort(alist, l, r):
    if r - l >= 1:
        mid = (r + l)//2
        mergeSort(alist, l, mid)
        mergeSort(alist, mid+1, r)

        i = l
        j = mid+1
        k = l
       temp_list = alist[:]
       while i < mid+1 and j < r+1:
            if temp_list[i] <= temp_list[j]:
                alist[k] = temp_list[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k] = temp_list[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < mid+1:
            alist[k] = temp_list[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < r+1:
            alist[k] = temp_list[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
```

From what I have been reading online the space complexities of my version and the one you can find at this link https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheMergeSort.html are `O(n)`. If you do it the way it is done in the link  it is easy to make the mistake of assuming space complexity is `O(nlogn)` but since all the stack frames are not "alive" together it is actually `O(n)` right ?

My version only creates an additional list of size `n` every time we are merging so I don't have extra space used on the stack for storing the left and right sublists.

So my questions are:

a) Even though both versions use `O(n)` space, does mine actually use less space than the one in the book by some constant factor or something ?

b) How about time complexity ? I don't think it has changed... but I am new to this stuff so maybe I screwed it up.

Thanks,

d_darric

Comment: Ok but at any point in time I only have one copy of the full list since I only do the merging on the “way up” in the recursion. And as soon as the merge operation is done the stack frame is “killed”. Basically I never have two copies of my list alive at the same time. Which is why I think I am still in `O(n)` space. Can you tell me where specifically is my reasoning false ?

Comment: Please refer to this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004903/is-the-space-complexity-for-these-2-mergesort-implementations-the-same> for the answer.