# Is the space complexity for these 2 mergesort implementations the same?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Hello I would like you to tell me if the space complexity for those 2 mergesort algorithms is the same.

Algo 1:

```
def mergeSort(alist, l, r):
    if r - l >= 1:
        mid = l + (r - l)//2

        mergeSort(alist, l, mid)
        mergeSort(alist, mid+1, r)

        i = l
        j = mid+1
        k = 0
        temp_list = [None]*(r-l+1)
        while i < mid+1 and j < r+1:
            if alist[i] <= alist[j]:
                temp_list[k] = alist[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                temp_list[k] = alist[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < mid+1:
            temp_list[k] = alist[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < r+1:
            temp_list[k] = alist[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

        n = 0
        for index in range(l,r+1):
            alist[index] = temp_list[n]
            n += 1
```

Algo 2:

```
def mergeSort2(alist):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort2(lefthalf)
        mergeSort2(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] <= righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
```

Intuitively for me Algo2 has a worse space complexity since the copied lists `lefthalf` and `righthalf` get pushed into the stack with the `mergeSort2` calling them.

Whereas Algo1 does not allocate extra space until the time to merge comes `temp_list = [None]*(r-l+1)` , so the execution stack has only the extra array for the `mergeSort` currently being executed.

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's assume that we have perfect garbage collection and every list is deallocated immediately after it falls out of use.

With this assumption, the algorithms have **the same big O space complexity**.

## Algorithm 2

Take a look at Algorithm 2 first and consider the following example:
Imagine you're sorting a list of length 16.

```
[15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

You compute the first and the second half of the list:

```
[15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8]  [7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

Then you sort the first half, in particular you divide it into two new sublists:

```
[15,14,13,12]  [11,10,9,8]
```

And you do the same again:

```
[15,14]  [13,12]
```

And again:

```
[15]  [14]
```

Only then you begin to merge the lists.

**What is the total length of lists allocated by the algorithm at that point?**

It is `16 + 2*8 + 2*4 + 2*2 + 2*1`. In general, it's `N + 2N/2 + 2N/4 + 2N/8 + ... + 2`. That's a simple geometric progression that sums to something around 3*N.

The algorithm also needs O(log(N)) space for the call stack, but that vanishes in the big O notation: *O(N)*

It is easy to see that this is the maximum of what the algorithm will use at any given point -- the length of allocated lists that will be used in the future (and cannot be deallocated because of that) will never exceed 3*N.

## Algorithm 1

Consider the same example again. We're to sort the following list.

```
[15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

Imagine that we have already sorted its first and second half:

```
[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Now, we need to allocate a temporary list of length N to perform the merge.
So at that moment we actively use two lists of length N, that gives us 2*N = O(N).

Again, it is easy to see that we'll never use more memory: the task of sorting the halves of the list naturally cannot cost more than sorting the list itself.

## Conclusion

Both algorithms use **O(N)** memory. They use O(log(N)) for the call stack, but that's a minor expense compared to O(N).

Knowing additionally that [Python uses reference counting](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/) to deallocate unused objects validates our initial assumption about garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful response. So basically they have the same space complexity in terms of O() notation but algo1 is actually better by a constant factor. And the further down the recursion tree the more significant that factor since when we are further down the tree algo1 will only have one extra list of size `n/2^k` with `k` being the depth whereas algo2 at that same point will have something closer to `3n` as you pointed out. So to conclude the discussion can we say that algo1 is better in terms of space complexity, but not significantly better ?

Comment: Yes, algorithm 1 has better constant (2 vs 3) hidden in the big O notation. Whether this is important or not depends on application. If the data you'd like to sort is really big, then constants start to make a difference. But again, if the data is really really big, you should probably be looking for an 'in place' sorting algorithm.